# Smiley emoticon appears in the code after writing \

Tags: texstudio, editors

Sometimes, while I'm writing a command, after pressing \, an emoticon appears in the editor, like this for example: \☺ . How can I get rid of this?

I use TeXstudio as Latex editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What does it appear as encoding (you can see it on the bottom left)?

Comment: Is it always the same emoticon or other characters too? And do you have a non-English keyboard layout? It might be related to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/6hsz2x/strange_unicode_chars_when_using_alt_gr/

Comment: @CarLaTeX I use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Is no the same emoticon always, they are also other simbols like a square, a diamon, .... I have a spanish keyword layout, I've read the reddit post but I dind't found any solution.

Comment: Related to https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/164? If you can find a way to *reliably* reproduce this behaviour, please post it there and let the developers know *how* to replicate what you are seeing. I myself have not experienced this at all, but it seems quite a number of people already do.

Comment: @Troy yeah, they have exactly the same problem that I have. I've not found any way to reproduce it, the weird characters appear randomly when I press rigth "Alt Gr" + key.

Comment: @DavidFernándezFernández do you happen to be using an external keyboard (connected via USB)? or is it like a laptop keyboard?

Comment: @Troy, it's a external keyboard connected via USB, evenly, I also have a laptop and have the same problem.

Comment: @TheDavtax Hmm okay interesting. Thanks for the feedback.